# Class function accepting objects of the same class

Tags: python, typing

Suppose we have a class:

```
from typing import List


class someClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.childs: List[someClass] = []

    def addChild(self, child: someClass) -> None:  # pyflakes: undefined name 'someClass'
        self.childs.append(child)


obj = someClass()
anotherobj = someClass()
obj.addChild(anotherobj)
```

It is understandable, because function `addChild` must be known before object of class is instantiated and there is no error in `List[someClass]` in `__init__`, because is will be evaluated at object instantiation and after class implementation.

One way to avoid this message is to define an empty class with the same name before:

```
from typing import List


class someClass:    # pylance: Class declaration is obscured by a declaration of the same name
    pass


class someClass:    # mypy: Name "someClass" already defined on line ##  [no-redef]
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.childs: List[someClass] = []

    def addChild(self, child: someClass) -> None:
        self.childs.append(child)


obj = someClass()
anotherobj = someClass()
obj.addChild(anotherobj)  # mypy: "someClass" has no attribute "addChild"  [attr-defined]
```

But in this case there are even more errors.

How to avoid these linters messages?

Comment: Related: [PEP 673 – Self Type](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/).